# RESTful Web Service in Payara/GlassFish

Tags: rest, maven, ejb, ear

I have a most simple RESTful Web Service like the following:

```
@Stateless
@Path("/list/instruments")
public class InstrumentsProvider {

@GET
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public String getAvailableInstruments() {

[..]

}
```

and

```
@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class RestApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        final Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<>();
        classes.add(InstrumentsProvider.class);
        return classes;
    }
}
```

The according `pom.xml` looks like this:

```
[..]
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <ejbVersion>3.1</ejbVersion>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
[..]
```

I deploy this ejb inside an ear file. The ear `pom.xml` looks like this:

```
[..]
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <modules>
                        <ejbModule>
                            <groupId>com.cmehistory</groupId>
                            <artifactId>rest-server</artifactId>
                        </ejbModule>
                    </modules>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
[..]
```

The resulting `ear` looks good, it contains all my libraries and the ejb `jar`.

I deploy to `Payara Server 4.1.2.173 #badassfish (build 24)`, server log reports successful deployment.

**Nevertheless, the web service seems not to be there.**

`[mydomain]:8080/rest/list/instruments/` returns 404.

I also tried `[mydomain]:8080/ear-0.0.1-SNAPSHOPT.jar/ejb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar/rest/list/instruments/` which gives also error 404.

I am not sure if I am just unable to find the correct URL or if the web service is not even there.

There is no war file inside the ear so far, just the ejb. I was reading this might cause problems, but I am not sure this applies for this case too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Packaging a RESTful web services `ejb` module **into an `ear` will not work**. They need a `war` archive that provides an web content to work.

To keep the web UI slim, web services can be packed inside **another `war` (no `ear`)** archive, which contains just the `ejb` module.